# gulp-autoprefixer unexpected Token

Tags: nodejs, gulp, gulp-4

Estoy migrando de gulp 3 a 4 y tengo un error que no se como solucionar:
en mi gulpFile tengo esto:

```
  var plug = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

  gulp.task('css', function() {
  return gulp.src(paths.css)
  .pipe(plug.rename({dirname: ''}))
  .pipe(isProduction() ? plug.concat('all.min.css') : noop())
  //.pipe(plug.autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 versions', '> 5%'] }))
  .pipe(plug.autoprefixer({
      browsers: { browsers: ['last 2 versions', '> 5%'] },
      cascade: false
    }))
  .pipe(isProduction() ? plug.minifyCss({}) : noop())
  .pipe(isProduction() ? plug.rev() : noop())
  .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.client + '/layout/css/'))
  .pipe(isProduction() ? plug.rev.manifest({merge:true}) : noop())
  .pipe(isProduction() ? gulp.dest('.') : noop());
});
```

Pero genera un error al hacer el plug.autoprefixer:

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`,

no entiendo porque sucede esto.

las versiones que uso son:
gulp: 4.0.2
gulp-load-plugins": "1.6.0"
gulp-autoprefixer": "7.0.1"
node: 6.13.0

con algunas versiones anteriores funciona bien:
gulp-load-plugins": "0.8.1"
gulp-autoprefixer": "2.3.1"

De igual forma intente hacer esto:

```
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
```

y sale el error de unexpected token